# numpy : fast substitution of uint8 value from a 2d array without any loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of uint8 which I will call `matrix` and a 1D array called `substitute` containing 256 uint8.

My code is the following but I need to get rid of loops :

```
def replaceValues(matrix, substitute) :
  rows = matrix.shape[0]
  cols = matrix.shape[1]
  return [ [ substitute[ matrix[i][j] ] for j in range(cols) ] for i in range(rows) ]
```

I have tried `numpy.vectorize` but it is kinda of slow.

Can you help ?

Comment: Can you provide examples of inputs and outputs of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ I think the question is pretty clear, even if there is no example of input and output, the explanation and the simple code fragment are enough to understand the goal of the OP.

Comment: @jdehesa One should read the code to guess that `matrix` contains indices of `substitute`. it's an important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done simply through [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in NumPy:

```
matrixWithReplacedValues = substitute[matrix]
```

Comment: Amazing.
I come from the old generation where you add to code everything, please be more understanding :)

Comment: @SebMa That's alright, that is what SO is for, I didn't mean to be rude or anything but sorry if you perceived it that way. I don't know the reason for the downvotes though (in the question or the answer).

Comment: Because I thought you did the down vote. But now I'm starting to believe this is done by either an administrator or a automatic system using word pattern matching such as `simply`, `simple`, `easy`, etc...

Comment: And I also thought the down vote concerned my question but it actually concerns your answer. I don't understand why your answer has been down voted because, I think your answer is GREAT !